# How to store latitude and longitude values

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I want to store the latitude and longitude values of an area to a variable called `town`. What is the most efficient/simplistic way of storing these values?

I've tried using

```
LatLng town = (x, y);
```

but, i'm am getting an error on the comma saying: expecting ) and another error on the closing bracket saying: expecting ;

Comment: Use [LatLng](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/LatLng#fields) to store latitude and longitude values.

Comment: @Lal: How do I initialize LatLng? I tried Latlng town = (x, y); but it didn't work

Comment: doesnt work means?

Comment: I get an error on the comma saying:  expecting )

Comment: you should do it as `LatLng town = new LatLng(x, y);`

Comment: And another error on the closing bracket saying: expecting ;

Comment: That's the right answer. Thank you

Comment: I've added that as my answer @Cian..could you please mark the answer as accepted if it really helped you.

Comment: Also, limit your number of decimal places, especially if you're using this as a key to a database. I'd recommend limiting yourself to two decimal places for town-level data. The table in the accepted answer for <a href="href://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8650/how-to-measure-the-accuracy-of-latitude-and-longitude">this question</a>  says two decimal places will give town-level data with a resolution of 1.1km.

Answer (score 2):

According to the docs, the public constructor for `LatLng` is

```
LatLng(double latitude, double longitude)
```

Thus, you should be using

```
LatLng town = new LatLng(x, y);
```

Please read more about `LatLng` in the [docs](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/LatLng#fields)